# Get hours in FormatDatTime by Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, tags, ms-flow, date-formatting

I want to retrieve the date of today not in utc but in central France to compare it with the time of a calendar event outlook ?

Comment: What is UTC offset value for Central France?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Convert time zone** action in Microsoft flow and specify the Destination time zone with UTC offset to Central France.

[image]

Check this question [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Formatting-Date-And-time-in-MS-Flow/td-p/71597) as example.

Here you can find a list of time zones: [Time Zone IDs (Compact 2013)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx).

If you want to format your string different you can use the following as a reference: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 0):

you can use following expression for example in the Step Condition or Set Variables:

```
convertFromUtc(utcNow(),1320)
```

this will convert a given timestamp (in this case utcNow()) to your target Timezone (1320 for Romance Standard Time).
for other Timezones see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg154758(v=winembedded.80)